# How to fix the below unknown type error from this simple c stack program?

Tags: c

I am not so much experienced with C language.

So I was trying to write a simple c program for stack but it's showing a bunch of error.

So may be i made something wrong in data elements.

Error Log:

```
stack.c:31:11: error: unknown type name ‘stack’
 void push(stack[],top){
           ^
stack.c:31:19: error: unknown type name ‘top’
 void push(stack[],top){
                   ^
stack.c:45:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘pop’ [enabled by default]
 void pop(stack,top){
      ^
stack.c:19:1: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘pop’ was here
 pop();
 ^
stack.c:54:6: warning: conflicting types for ‘traverse’ [enabled by default]
 void traverse(stack,top){
      ^
stack.c:22:1: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘traverse’ was here
 traverse();
 ^
stack.c: In function ‘traverse’:
stack.c:62:20: error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector
 printf("%d\n",stack[i]);
```

Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
   int stack[10];
   int i;
   int choice;
   printf("Enter the elementz\n");
   for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      scanf("%d",&stack[i]);
      printf("++++++++ MENU ++++++++\n\n\n");
      printf("Enter 1 to push \n Enter 2 to pop\n Enter 3 to display \n\n\n");
      printf("Enter you choice \n\n\n");
      scanf("%d",&choice);
      switch(choice){
         case 1 :
            push();
            break;
         case 2:
            pop();
            break;
         case 3 :
            traverse();
            break;
         default:
            printf("Enter the correct choice\n");


      }
   }
}

void push(stack[],top){
   int item;
   int max = 10;
   printf("Enter the number you want to input\n");
   scanf("%d",&item);
   if(top == stack[max]-1){
      printf("It's full\n");
   }
   else{
      top = top+1;
      stack[top] = item;

   }
}

void pop(stack,top){

   if(top == -1){
      printf("STack is empty\n");
   }
   else{
      top = top-1;
   }
}

void traverse(stack,top){
   int i;
   if(top == -1){
      printf("WHy r u giving m empty stack to print");
   }
   else{
      for (i = 0; i <10; i++){
         printf("Your stack is : \n");
         printf("%d\n",stack[i]);
      }
   }
}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please take some time to understand the basics of declaring, defining, and using functions in C. It's not useful to provide answers to such basic concepts here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answers to the OP's problem can be found in any basic textbook on C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You must write type names for each function argument. (the cause of error you posted)
- You must declare or define functions to use *before* using them. (the cause of error you posted)
- You must pass arguments that functions to use requires to functions. (the cause of error you posted)
- Modifications to passed arguments won't affect caller's local variables, so you must use pointers to have callee modify them.
- The condition to check if the stack is full is wrong.
- The loop condition in `traverse()` looks strange.
- Reading elements of the stack and doing stack manipulation based on chosen menus in the same loop looks strange because reading elements will corrupt the stack dealt with the menu.
- You should use standard `int main(void)` in hosted environment instead of `void main()`, which is illegal in C89 and implementation-defined in C99 or later, unless you have some special reason to use non-standard signature.
- You should format your code properly with indent.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void push(int stack[],int* top);
void pop(int stack[],int* top);
void traverse(int stack[],int top);
int main(void){
    int stack[10];
    int top = 9;
    int i;
    int choice;
    printf("Enter the elementz\n");
    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        scanf("%d",&stack[i]);
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        printf("++++++++ MENU ++++++++\n\n\n");
        printf("Enter 1 to push \n Enter 2 to pop\n Enter 3 to display \n\n\n");
        printf("Enter you choice \n\n\n");
        scanf("%d",&choice);
        switch(choice){
            case 1 :
                push(stack,&top);
                break;
            case 2:
                pop(stack,&top);
                break;
            case 3 :
                traverse(stack,top);
                break;
            default:
                printf("Enter the correct choice\n");


        }
    }
}
void push(int stack[],int* top){
    int item;
    int max = 10;
    printf("Enter the number you want to input\n");
    scanf("%d",&item);
    if(*top == max-1){
        printf("It's full\n");
    }
    else{
        *top = *top+1;
        stack[*top] = item;

    }
}
void pop(int stack[],int* top){

    if(*top == -1){
        printf("STack is empty\n");
    }
    else{
        *top = *top-1;
    }
}
void traverse(int stack[],int top){
    int i;
    if(top == -1){
        printf("WHy r u giving m empty stack to print");
    }
    else{
        for (i = 0; i <= top; i++){
            printf("Your stack is : \n");
            printf("%d\n",stack[i]);
        }
    }
}
```